# Determine square root of 3 by drawing a straight line

Tags: quadratics, radicals

There is a quadratic function $(x+1) (x-3)$.

Determine the value of the square root of 3 by drawing a suitable straight line

I have got no thought here hence there are no workings.

Any help here would be highly appreciated:)

Comment: Is it $x^2 - 2x -3 $ or $(x+1)(x+3)$ ?

Comment: Both the functions stand for the same the original in the problem was given brackets and the expanded function is the other. Both are literally the same

Comment: Not really... $(x+1)(x+3) = x^2 + 4x + 3$.. I'll assume you meant $(x+1)(x-3)$

Comment: Yes my apology I expanded wrong I will edit the question

Comment: I imagine this question is based on a preliminary drawing of the parabola with equation $y=x^2-2x-3.$

Comment: Yes  you are absolutely correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $x = \sqrt 3$ satisfies the equation $$f(x) = -2x$$
Here, $f(x) = x^2 - 2x -3 $

Now, If we were to draw the line $y=-2x$, and find it's point of intersection with our given curve, we would then drop the perpendicular from that point to $x$ axis. This would give us the value of $\sqrt 3$

Comment: of course what do you exactly mean by satisfies the equation

Comment: By satisfies, I mean if we defined a new function $g(x) = f(x)+2x$, then $g(\sqrt 3) = 0 $